# Get result of each test case executed in Xcode UI tests

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, xctestcase

I need the test status after each test case is executed in my test suite in Xcode. I know an observer can help in achieving it. But how do I use it in my tests?

Comment: Please elaborate more. And also dont forget to mention what you have tried so far so that altruists can help you in a better efficient way

Comment: It would be helpful if you said exactly **why** you need this, or what your use case is, because individual unit tests are normally made to be standalone.

Comment: Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: I need to integrate my tests results with TestRail, a test management tool. Once each test is executed, I need to make an API call to update the result. I saw some posts on using an observer..but they weren't clear enough. I'll append a test case ID to each test, and send the ID and result as params in the API call. I think using an observer and getting the result from the function "testCase(_:didFailWithDescription:inFile:atLine:)"  (a method in XCTestObservation) will help me getting the tests which fail. However, I'm not sure if that's the solution.

Comment: I have written the tests in Swift.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right track and can achieve what you're wanting to do via the XCTestObservation protocol (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestobservation). You can add an observer to your test case class and I'd recommend doing this in the setUp() method since it gets executed before each test method.

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    continueAfterFailure = false

    XCUIApplication().launch()

    XCTestObservationCenter.shared.addTestObserver(UITestObserver())
}
```

To do this you should implement a class that conforms to the XCTestObservation protocol and then provide your own implementation to the methods of interest to perform whatever actions you need/want. In your case you're probably going to want to provide an implementation for this method...

```
optional public func testCase(_ testCase: XCTestCase, didFailWithDescription description: String, inFile filePath: String?, atLine lineNumber: Int)
```

Here's a quick example of what this test observer class might look like...

```
import XCTest

public class UITestObserver: NSObject, XCTestObservation {
    public func testCase(_ testCase: XCTestCase,
                           didFailWithDescription description: String,
                           inFile filePath: String?,
                           atLine lineNumber: Int) {
        print("failure description: \(description)")
        print("failed test case: \(testCase)")
        if let filePath = filePath {
            print("failure at file path: \(filePath)")
        }
        print("failure at line: \(lineNumber)")
    }
}
```

This function I provided an example of above gets called whenever one of your test cases fails, so you don't need to "do" anything from within your test case class or methods.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Khazana would you mind accepting my answer as a solution, please? :)

Comment: you might need to override the other methods descriptions as well.

Answer (score 1):

The result of each test case executed is saved on a file named  ***TestSummeries.plist.

You will find it under

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<your-app-name>/Logs/Test/****_TestSummeries.plist
```

If you run your test many times just delete the everything inside DerivedData before execution. Then you will find only one TestSummeries.plist.

Then parse the plist and get your desired data from the plist file.

** If you need more information about it feel free to comment below.

Comment: Yeah, the results are stored in that file, but I was looking for a more efficient way as I am going to automate this entire process of updating the test results to TestRail, and it needs to be a seamless one. I shouldn't have to manually delete the data in cases where the tests run more than once.